# How to add a scrollbar in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery table to show my data. There I have 2 buttons previous and next for pagination. But I want to add a scroll bar in the bottom of the table. I wrote

```
overflow:scroll
```

in CSS, but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Query Result Page</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/jdpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" ></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
    //this is the jQuery function for table //                
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tableData').dataTable();
    } );
    </script>

    // these are the CSS classes that will create the table look and feel 
    <table class="tableData context-menu-one" id="tableData" style="overflow-x: scroll ">
        <thead>    // this is column for tables which will contain the values from the database //
            <tr style="font-size: 14px;" >
                <th width="20%" align="left">Name</th>
                <th width="20%" align="left">Class</th>
                <th width="20%" align="left">Roll</th>
                <th width="20%" align="left">Address</th>
                <th width="20%" align="left">Marks</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>    
        // this is table values here we  will list some values dynamically which will come from database
        <tr style="font-size: 14px;" >
            <th width="20%" align="left">john</th>
            <th width="20%" align="left">9</th>
            <th width="20%" align="left">47</th>
            <th width="20%" align="left">mumbai</th>
            <th width="20%" align="left">52</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Someone please help me

Comment: What did you apply the overflow to?

Comment: besides: it may be not the solution you asked for, but perhaps it is of some help http://datatables.net/

Comment: basically, table doesnot have scrollbar...

Answer (score 1):

The overflow property must be applied on the table container and not the table itself.

If the scrollbar is not appearing, it's because the table width is less than the container width.